# How to produce DateTimeOffset string from Noda Time OffsetDateTime in a default for a current culture format?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, nodatime

Suppose I have Noda Time LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime and Offset myOffset variables. To produce a DateTimeOffset string in ISO8601 format I use

```
var offsetDateTimePattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create(OffsetDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern.PatternText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultOffsetDateTime);
var resDateTimeOffsetISO8601 = offsetDateTimePattern.Format(new OffsetDateTime(myLocalDateTime, myOffset));
```

Now, I also want to produce DateTimeOffset string in a in a default for a current culture format.

For USA it would be like "4/10/2014 3:03:11 PM -07:00". I was thinking about using a combination of "G" pattern with CurrentCulture for DateTime part followed by "m" format for Offset. How would I do that? Something like using "G m" as a pattern text?

```
var offsetDateTimePatternLocal = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("G m", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, defaultOffsetDateTime);
var resDateTimeOffsetCurrentCulture = offsetDateTimePattern.Format(new OffsetDateTime(myLocalDateTime, myOffset));
```

(Related parsing question was asked here: http://goo.gl/OVeQJT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you could do if you want to preserve the culture-aware behavior of the `"G"` formatter is something like this:

```
var ldtPattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithCurrentCulture("G");
var offsetPattern = OffsetPattern.CreateWithCurrentCulture("m");
var result = ldtPattern.Format(localDateTime) + " " + offsetPattern.Format(resOffset);
```

The problem is that `OffsetDateTimePattern` doesn't have any culture-aware standard patterns.  [See the user guide for details](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/offsetdatetime-patterns.html).  I think this should probably be rectified in a future version.

If you want to format with a fixed pattern, you could.  But then you'd need to know the pattern for the culture in advance.

```
var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt o<m>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultOffsetDateTime);
var result = pattern.Format(new OffsetDateTime(localDateTime, resOffset));
```

Comment: Great, I actually thought of trying exactly that!

Comment: New issue created for this: https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=276